# Missing element from array (D&C) - code design/aesthetic improvement

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, array, bitwise

I am trying to implement in C/C++ a 'classical' Divide and Conquer algorithm which solves the following problem "Given an array of n-1 numbers (int) from 0 to n, find the missing number".

I am using the typical algorithm: 
start from MSB
(1) find out how many bits of 1, 0 I should have (MSB bits)
(2) find out how many bits of 1, 0 I actually have (MSB bits)

split the array into 2 subarrays: one with MSBs of 0, the other with MSBs of 1.
By using (1) and (2) I figure out in which subarray my number should be and I recursively call the function for the next bit (MSB-1), until my subarray contains only 1 element.

I've written the code, and it works, but I have the feeling that it isn't really that aesthetic (the function has a lot of parameters), because I had some difficulties.

Let's say that we have v = {0,1,2,3,5,6,7}.
exp1 = 4 (expected number of "1" MSB bits).
I know how to calculate exp1, because I know that one number is missing from 0 to 7.
act1 = 3 (actual ...)
So, we will have something like this: 0 1 2 3 | 5 6 7.
Because act1 < exp1, we recursively call the function for the 5 6 7 part and for MSB-1.

exp1 = ? I will be unable to calculate this, because I will have no information upon the missing number. That is why I use the **flagR** and **flagL** flags. So that I know which part of the array I recursively called in order to compute exp1. But I really don't like the fact that I have been forced to use this 'trick'.

I have noticed myself that I should've forced an order in the partitioning process: the numbers that have 0 as MSB (current MSB) should be in the first part, the others in the second. I will rewrite the code.

The main() function isn't really that important for now, it serves for testing, currently.

Here is my spaghetti code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

// get bit #j from int i
unsigned int get_bit(int i, int j)
{
  return i & (1<<j);
}

int find(int v[], int left, int right, int max_bit, int flagL, int flagR)
{
  if (left == right)
    if (flagR != 0)
      return v[left] + 1;
    if (flagL != 0)
      return v[left] - 1;
  else
  {
    int exp0 = 0; // expected bits of 0
    int act0 = 0; // actual bits of 0
    int act1 = 0; // actual bits of 1
    int exp1 = 0; // expected bits of 1

    for (int i=left+flagL;i<=right+flagR;i++)
      if (get_bit(i,max_bit) == 0)
        exp0++;
      else
        exp1++;

    for (int i=left;i<=right;i++)
      if (get_bit(v[i],max_bit) == 0)
        act0++;
      else
        act1++;

    // val_cur is the max_bit of the pivot (v[right])
    unsigned int val_cur = get_bit(v[right],max_bit);
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int man = 0;

    // divides the array into 2 subarrays
    // one subarray contains elements with max_bit = 0
    // the other contains elements with max_bit = 1
    for (k=1;k<right;k++)
    {
      if (get_bit(v[k],max_bit) == val_cur)
      {
        i++;
        man = v[i];
        v[i] = v[k];
        v[k] = man;
      }
    }
    i++;
    man = v[i];
    v[i] = v[k];
    v[k] = man;
    // i is the "border" between the subarrays

    // recursively call the function for the next bit (max_bit-1)
    // and with the correct partition
    if (get_bit(v[i],max_bit) == 1)
      if (act1 < exp1)
        return find(v,left,i,max_bit-1,0,1);
      else
        return find(v,i+1,right,max_bit-1,-1,0);
    else
      if (act0 < exp0)
        return find(v,left,i,max_bit-1,0,1);
      else
        return find(v,i+1,right,max_bit-1,-1,0);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n = 7;
  int v[] = {7,0,4,1,3,6,2};

  // find the maximum number of bits
  int bits = 0; 
  bits = floor(log(n*1.0)/log(2*1.0));

  // call the function
  printf("%d",find(v,0,6,bits,0,1));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't follow the definition:

```
"Given an array of n-1 numbers (int) from 0 to n, find the missing number".
```

So if n == 7, as in your example code, there should be 6 numbers (n-1) in the
array.  There are 8 numbers in the the range "0 to n" (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).
Perhaps the problem definition meant "0 to n-1" or "0 up to n, not including
n".

Your example code has seven numbers and n == 7:

```
int n = 7;
int v[] = {7,0,4,1,3,6,2};
```

I would expect n to be 8 for an array of 7 numbers where one of the 8 is
missing.

Anyway, your example works, printing '5', but if you replace, say the 2 with a 5
it now prints '3'.  Unless I messed up!

---

On the code, **C ignores white space** (unlike say Python).  Look at the
if-else chain at the beginning of `find`:

```
if (left == right) 
  if (flagR != 0)
    return v[left] + 1;
  if (flagL != 0)
    return v[left] - 1;
else
{
  int exp0 = 0; // expected bits of 0
```

According to the indentation of statements, you intended the `if (flagR != 0)`
and `if (flagL != 0)` to be dependent upon `left == right`, as in:

```
if (left == right) {
    if (flagR != 0) {
        return v[left] + 1;
    }
    if (flagL != 0) {
        return v[left] - 1;
    }
}
else {
    int exp0 = 0; // expected bits of 0
```

But what the compiler will see is

```
if (left == right) {
    if (flagR != 0) {
        return v[left] + 1;
    }
}
if (flagL != 0) {
    return v[left] - 1;
}
else {
    int exp0 = 0; // expected bits of 0
```

If you get the editor to re-indent the code for you (or use UNIX `indent`
command), you will see that your indenting is wrong.  The lesson is always to
use braces to say explicitly what you mean.

The same goes for your other expressions:

```
for (int i=left+flagL;i<=right+flagR;i++)
  if (get_bit(i,max_bit) == 0)
    exp0++;
  else
    exp1++;
```

should be more like this:

```
for (int i = left + flagL; i <= right + flagR; i++) {
    if (get_bit(i, max_bit) == 0) {
        exp0++;
    } else {
        exp1++;
    }
}
```

In this case, there is no misunderstanding by the compiler but you should add the braces nevertheless - consider what happens if you don't add explicit braces with:

```
for (int i=left+flagL;i<=right+flagR;i++)
  if (get_bit(i,max_bit) == 0)
    exp0++;
  else
    exp1++;
    something_else();
```

Comment: Thanks for the review!
At the 
    `if (left == right)`

     an
      `else
        if (flagL != 0)
          return v[left] - 1;`

should do the trick without braces. (But I've forgotten the else).

Comment: Just use braces.  You wont find many reviews here of C code where reviewers don't point out missing braces.  You might think they are not necessary or ugly, but standard best practice says you are wrong :-)